# Sorting interface in Go

Tags: json, go, interface, marshalling, unmarshalling

Been googling and stacking around for the solution with no success.

I'm importing a JSON file to an struct, however, when I want to use it, the values come out in a random order. This is an example of my JSON file:

```
"Assets": {
    "asset1": "asset1.png",
    "asset2": "asset2.png"
  },
  "Colors": {
    "MainColor": [
      {
        "red": 247,
        "green": 0,
        "blue": 247
      }
    ],
    "MainGradient": [
      {
        "red": 9,
        "green": 103,
        "blue": 170
      },
      {
        "red": 18,
        "green": 138,
        "blue": 221
      }
    ]
}
```

I can import the JSON using Unmarshal, however, when I print it, the "red, green,blue" values outputs in random order, like this:

```
[{map[asset1:asset1.png asset2:asset2.png] {[map[red:247 green:0 blue:247]] [map[green:103 red:9 blue:170] map[green:138 blue:221 red:18]]}}]
```

As you can see, the RGB values come at random order every time. I want to know if there's a way to always output the in the same order: red, green, blue.

Thank you.

Comment: sort before you output..

Comment: Just fyi might want to revise your question a bit as the problem you're actually encountering is how to display data. There is no sorting happening here and nothing to sort. If you decided to sort the `MainGradient` array by the sum of RGB values descending, that would be a sort. From what I can tell, you just want to format the data you have in memory different. If that's not the case please offer correction but neither a map, nor a struct (which are the only two options for housing the data in the RGB objects) has any notion of order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maps are unordered, both in Go and per the JSON spec. You will have to call them in order as you need them.

```
r, g, b := color["red"], color["green"], color["blue"]
```

You can also unmarshal the values into a struct, which will give you a deterministic layout:

```
type Color struct {
    Red   int `json:"red"`
    Green int `json:"green"`
    Blue  int `json:"blue"`
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/0l01NxJ4dq

Comment: Thank you JimB, It does what I needed to do. The Playground example was perfect for my needs. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

While I personally would take the route JimB describes above another option is just to change how you display the data. I can infer based on your output that you did; `fmt.Printf("%v", YourInstance)`. The order of the items in the map is irrelevant if you explicitly specify where each goes with a format string like;

```
fmt.Printf("red: %v, green: %v, blue: %v\n", ColorInstance["red"], ColorInstance["green"], ColorInstance["blue"])
```

Now that only prints a single instance so to print the whole thing you'd need further logic but that's the basic idea.

If you want things in order, a map is not the structure for you. If you want quick access based on a key, then a map is a good choice. If you just want to format your output for writing to console or a file or whatever, it can be done easily with a map but personally I think, JimB's suggestion is the best way to approach deserializing and processing data like that. My philosophy is to make the structures as concrete as possible. You get the work out of the way up front and have cleaner, more concise, better performing code there after.